# Flushall in redis leads to loading the dataset in memory error

Tags: docker, redis

How do I "FLUSHALL" in redis in this situation?

Running redis via docker on PopOs 21.0.4 as shown in the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:5-alpine
    command: redis-server --save "" --appendonly yes
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "${PWD}//redis/data:/data"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Connecting to redis-cli and issuing a FLUSHALL (or FLUSHDB) command and I get the error:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> FLUSHALL
(error) LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory
```

Here is docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.10
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.9
 Git commit:        b485636
 Built:             Mon Oct 25 07:43:13 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.10
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.9
  Git commit:       e2f740d
  Built:            Mon Oct 25 07:41:20 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.11
  GitCommit:        5b46e404f6b9f661a205e28d59c982d3634148f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/4624) about that error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message means that Redis is still loading data, i.e. in your case, the AOF file. You cannot run `FLUSHALL` until the loading finishes.

If you don't need the data to be loaded, you can delete the AOF file before starting Redis.